# Change variable numbers permanently VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button which copies columns n & i and paste on n+3 & i+3, but after the columns n&i need to change to n+3 & i+3. I tried to do that by adding `n = n + 3
i = i + 3` on the end of the code, but it's not working.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

n = 22
i = 24
Range(Columns(n), Columns(i)).Copy
Range(Columns(n + 3), Columns(i + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

Columns(n + 3).ClearContents


n = n + 3
i = i + 3

End Sub
```

Comment: They lose scope when the Sub exits. You need to either put them in module level variables or use some other kind of persistence (like a hidden worksheet).

Comment: See [variables & scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2957/variables#t=201702091912202961978) on Docs.SO.

Comment: Thanks, managed to do it by placing the numbers 22 & 24 on another worksheet and adding +3 to them.

Comment: Besides the scoping issue, you are initializing n and i everytime you enter the macro. See my proposal to avoid a "helper" sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to declare the variables as `Static`:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Static n As Integer
    Static i As Integer

    If n = 0 Then n = 22
    If i = 0 Then i = 24

    Range(Columns(n), Columns(i)).Copy
    Range(Columns(n + 3), Columns(i + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

    n = n + 3
    i = i + 3
End Sub
```

Note that if you do this, you'll need to add the "initialization code" for the first time the macro is run.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your variables to a cell. For example, you place n's value is cell A1, and i's value in cell B1.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer

n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
i = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
Range(Columns(n), Columns(i)).Copy
Range(Columns(n + 3), Columns(i + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

Columns(n + 3).ClearContents


n = n + 3
i = i + 3

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = n
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        n = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Columns(.Columns.Count).Column - 2, 22)
    End With
    i = n + 2
    Range(Columns(n), Columns(i)).Copy
    Range(Columns(n + 3), Columns(i + 3)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats

    Columns(n + 3).ClearContents
End Sub
```